# oAuth2 client with custom token passed isn't valid

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, next.js

I'm trying to modify the node.js google calendar api https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs to fit my next.js application. So far I got my auth setup like this

```
  providers: [
    Providers.Google({
      clientId: "id",
      clientSecret: "secret",
      authorizationUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?prompt=consent&access_type=offline&response_type=code',
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.secret,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
      if (account?.accessToken) {
        token.refresh_token = account.refreshToken
        token.token_type = account.token_type
        token.access_token = account.accessToken;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
})
```

But when I pass my own token, which is identical to the token google gets it just reject my oauth client with the message `The API returned an error: Error: unauthorized_client`

here's the entire api route that gets the tokens https://gist.github.com/MislavPeric/ba5e4aaef3c84a88d3ee83ee55630ca9

token google returns in token.json in unmodified example (as shown in their documentation)

```
{
  "access_token": "ya29.a0AasdeAmAoGF5BwEev7PS1RLaT0ZvV0v1N9HNAdQb0iMlyGaCpVuBYN2B-Vb-eBK0U",
  "refresh_token": "1//09Basd0yLcen8bG5BbVutOjx3fEAYcHCrvnqZSWXewdU",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expiry_date": 1616867523497
}
```

token I pass with the information that gets returned from the google login

```
{
  access_token: 'ya29.a0AfH6SMB-h_QBKYdj3sdsadsa8uiEMzVGVqv00NZgjCvrJqy',
  refresh_token: '1//0sadsada',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expiry_date: 1616864309869
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by custom token?  You cant create your own token tokens to access the API must come from and be created by Google's Authentication server.  Please edit your question and show us how you are creating this token.

Comment: Custom token was bad wording. I'm using the tokens google provided from the google login

Comment: What google login we need an [example] of your issue please.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the official Node.js [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) to see how to connect to Google Calendar.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Calendar API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listEvents(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Make sure you created [installed credentials](https://youtu.be/qwqJcyLQSSQ) on google developer console for this sample and enable the Google drive API.

Comment: This example functioned properly for me. The issue is it does not fit my use case. I need to be able to pass the user information from my backend to next API route and skip the authorization via the command line for obvious reasons. The idea is that the user logs in using `next-auth` and from there calendar data gets fetched automatically